# Running WebJobs within an Azure Worker Role

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-worker-roles

I do have a **AzureWorker** that receives SMTP messages from TCP ports and pushes them to queues. Other threads pick up these messages from the queues and process them. Currently, process threads have their queue polling logic. Simply they check the queues and increase wait interval if the queues are empty.

I want to simplify the queue logic and make use of other **Webjobs** functionalities in this **AzureWorker**.

Is it possible to start a **WebJobs** thread in this **AzureWorker** and let that thread handle the details? Are there any limitations that I need to know?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Worker Roles are a feature of Azure Cloud Services. Azure Web Jobs are a feature of Azure App Service. They are both built to provide similar ability to run background process tasks within the context of your application. Although, since they are features of different Azure services they can't be run together like you are asking in a nested fashion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to start a WebJobs thread in this AzureWorker and let that thread handle the details?

I agree with Chris Pietschmann, it does not enable us to start WebJobs thread directly in Azure Worker Role.

> Other threads pick up these messages from the queues and process them. Currently, process threads have their queue polling logic. Simply they check the queues and increase wait interval if the queues are empty.
>
> I want to simplify the queue logic and make use of other Webjobs functionalities in this AzureWorker.

If you’d like to complete this task by using WebJobs, you could write a program and run as a  WebJobs in your Azure App Service. And [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) provides a way to dynamically start/stop WebJobs via REST API, you could use it to manage your WebJobs in your Worker Role.